# PHPStorm disable html-syntax highlighting in PHP string

Tags: ide, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

In PHPStorm 3.0, a PHP string like:

```
$sString = '<div><span class="someClass">test</span></div>';
```

has HTML Syntax / opening and closing brackets highlighting.

I would like to disable this behavior and display it as a string only.

Anyone figured out where I can change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the string, **Un-inject Language**:

[image: un-inject]

Comment: If that particular option doesn't appear (because reasons, I couldn't find it), you can also disable it in Settings -> Editor -> Language Injections: uncheck `php: "<html>"`